# What is the proper way to escape an equals ( "=" ) in a custom form with xslt?

Tags: xslt, url, html, anchor-tags

I have a display form which has an anchor tag in a table cell somewhere like the following:

```
    <a href="../../Lists/SomeFilteredListView?FilterField1=field1&FilterValue1={@field1}">
           <xsl:value-of select="@field2"/>
    </a>
```

I can embed a simple link like this in the form just fine. However, when I started rebuilding the url from left to right, I noticed that it stopped working once I added anything after "FilterField1" which leads me to believe that the "=" character is causing the issue.

What is the proper way of escaping the "=" character in order to add a url with a query string into a form that uses xslt?

edit: I wrapped the string in braces:

```
href="{'../../Lists/SomeFilteredListView?FilterField1=field1'}"
```

which worked.. but it stopped working once I added the second part (&FilterValue1=, etc.).

Comment: Try `%26` to replace the &. = is `%2D`.

Comment: This also works if I encode the entire string (i.e., make the two replacements you suggested). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue with the equals sign, the issue is with the ampersand, that has to be escaped as `&amp;`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml

There are 5 characters that need to be escaped in XML:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I still think there is some sort of issue with the equals sign. If I don't enclose the string in braces and single quotes, the equals sign alone breaks it.

Comment: You only have to enclose any values you would be referencing like `{@field1}`. See additional link.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. It looks like the equals only caused an issue when it was left at the end of the string. Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score -3):

Replace & with "& amp;" and = with "& quote;"